# Get type's keys based on the type of one of its values

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a global type definition which is an object with keys (what I call a `prop`) that the user has to pass as parameter to `myFunction()`, and values which are used only by my code to do type checking.

Values can be of only 3 "possible types" (contained in `Possible`). Each possible type has a different type definition.

I would like `myFunction()` to accept as parameter only `props` whose value's `test` property is `"possible1"`.

The generic type `OnlyPossible1Props<T>` shows the way I would implement this, but it doesn't work.

First, an error is shown:

> Type 'prop' cannot be used to index type 'T'. (2536)

And in addition, it returns `string | number` instead of `"abc" | "def"` in `myFunction()`.

The closest thing I've been able to do is the piece of code I commented out. However, it loses the information of the key along the way because I don't keep it somewhere.

For an easiest way to debug, here's a [link to the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBtoF4oCIyIoYQCMuUAPngUmpgEzlX6F0QDMuA3AFA+iQoANQCG6AK4QAQiIQQAPABUoEAB7AIAOwAmCWK2IAaKAFVjQgHxQcAbx5QHUDQmAAuKIsP3HcYAAsIACcSdzNvB18AwPp3IR4AX15+cGhRCVIlKxw0yRk5eRZaYjJjTw8LXgFUsUl6TOthGulZBUKiBlxS4wBtMsUAXQrkwRyOeuymvNaado5Oj1LuwaSqqAARCAAzZE1kYGQ4TQa7RyhusEC4MHcXQJ2Ac37YppJ5EU0QKypRuvfPyka6XYbw+FgSSR2GkCmxEAGNoABRVQiAC2YEwKnUWl06y2Oz2ByOJ0cuBEqFhuHcxNODmcbmoBkwJXCNMiQRCUFuDxZpzZ0RuwDumnuLPiXlOuG0W0pUGpNLp7jabGZNJ8-nZAqFItVEXV-M5gu5pzFLNw9z8yBlctOCoZRQ64p1fI5XOFPLVURiZ1d92MPv6osdDlwACsANboK3u2kQFyKmZsThB1l6l2Gt06qB8r0+paihJ8AD0hacKSgAHlNOgQPB7aQYJcwAhxh5MRodHo4KgQxBYcAoAB+HjFmmKbphiAgOCbDz9NvYvQ7TZBKAAQUHw5Lp3XanbOJsTlj9KVxXI8U3NIHa6g7k0EAAbivbw+n1A74-Aisy5Xq7XZiQGyuZtFCyVtdwXLNu17fsh1OCcpxnZRwI7KAlxXC4rg3U4xwwsA52QnE0MCa9YMcHcsRQg9bRPJkzxZK9cJvN8X2I58PyY99X04z8+E2cRND7QkoBREAADF+MEw55EAsB5xQn8a0ZetG2bJFUXRCALAsAAKXD3BkgBKWUoHiIA).

```js
type Possible = "possible1" | "possible2" | "possible3";

type ValueBase<T extends Possible, U, V> = {
    test: T,
    other1: U,
    other2: V
};

type Value1<T> = ValueBase<"possible1", T, T>;
type Value2<T> = ValueBase<"possible2", T, [T, T]>;
type Value3<T> = ValueBase<"possible3", T, T[]>;

type Definition = {
    [prop: string]: Value1<any> | Value2<any> | Value3<any>
};

interface Example extends Definition {
    "abc": {
        test: "possible1",
        other1: string
        other2: string
    },
    "def": {
        test: "possible1",
        other1: string
        other2: string
    },
    "ghi": {
        test: "possible2",
        other1: string
        other2: [string, string]
    },
    "jkl": {
        test: "possible3",
        other1: string
        other2: string[]
    }
}

// type OnlyPossible1Props<T> = T extends object ?
//     T[keyof T] extends infer A ?
//     A extends { test: "possible1" }
//     ? A : never : never : never;

type OnlyPossible1Props<T> = T extends object ?
    keyof T extends infer prop ?
    T[prop] extends infer A ?
    A extends { test: "possible1" }
    ? prop : never : never : never : never;

function myFunction<Prop extends OnlyPossible1Props<Example>>(prop: Prop) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, but only if you remove `extends Definition` from `Example`:

```
type OnlyPossible1Props<T> = {
    [K in
        { [J in keyof T]: T[J] extends { test: "possible1" } ? J : never }[keyof T]
    ]?: T[K]
};
```

This results in:

```
type ExampleOnlyPossible1Props = OnlyPossible1Props<Example>;

// equivalent to:

type ExampleOnlyPossible1Props = {
    abc?: {
        test: "possible1";
        other1: string;
        other2: string;
    };
    def?: {
        test: "possible1";
        other1: string;
        other2: string;
    };
}
```

(You may want to skip the optional modifier `?`).

This gives us:

```
myFunction({ "abc": { test: "possible1", other1: "foo", other2: "bar" } }) // OK
myFunction({ "def": { test: "possible2", other1: ["a", "b"], other2: "bcd" } }) // Error
```

You can see that in this [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBtoF4oCIyIoYQCMuUAPngUmpgEzlX6F0QDMuA3AFA+iQoANQCG6AK4QAQiIQQAPABUoEAB7AIAOwAmCWK2IAaKAFVjQgHxQcAbx5QHUDQmAAuKIsP3HcYAAsIACcSdzNvB18AwPp3IR4AX15+cGhRCVIlKxw0yRk5eRZaYjJjTw8LXgFUsUl6TOthGulZBUKiBlxS4wBtMsUAXQrkwRyOeuymvNaado5Oj1LuwaSqqAARCAAzZE1kYGQ4TQa7RyhugGkoHagXQJ2Ac37YppJ5EU0QKypRuvfPyka6XYbw+FgSSR2GkCmxEAGNoABRVQiAC2YEwUBOjlwIlQsNw7ixpwczjc1AMmBK4WJkSCIRuwDumnu1NOtOi7luD2p8S8p1w2i2BMxrMcpPcbTYVOJPn8dM5jO5Moico5DKZLNOvOpuHufmQwqJxPF5KKHT5yvZ9K5zNFKqiMTONvuxmd-R5FocuAAVgBrdCGu1OCAuCUzNicT001XWxW25VQdmO51LHkJPirAAaDV9EBAcE2UCRqPREBWKSgAHlNOgQPAzaQYIE4GAEOMRacLldNEGbGcAFLdqC5-OFgbuRTdfv9FTqLS6THB0Om2ZkKDxKAAfigg-cmggADcguvuiOCx53ad+puJxd3YkMxWAGJwOANau1+urpsttvFtGYEMPCbOImiwvshxQCiIBPqB4EHJo8g-mAs4aDoegfnWFKNs2rbyP+pYWBYAAUYC4e4yEAJSLvEfDQbBYEQZoxF9jieKGkuZKSsU8xWhKmyvrxqqOrgqAiIE5AbvE1EAPQyVW5w8PRcFMSxeCCpsHEmtx5qJjG7jdDi8yibg-TGEmEp4toknrrJ8kIoEzaBDwQA).

The reason this does not work if `Example extends Definition` is that the index signature on `Definition` means `keyof Example` evaluates to `string | number`, rather than the actual keys of `Example`. If `extends Definition` is removed, we get `keyof Example` as `"abc" | "def" | "ghi" | "jkl"`.

If you want `myFunction` to accept *one of* the `possible1` props from `Example`, you can instead use:

```
type OnlyPossible1Props<T> = {
    [J in keyof T]: T[J] extends { test: "possible1" } ? T[J] : never
}[keyof T];
```

This gives you a union type that you can see that in this [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBtoF4oCIyIoYQCMuUAPngUmpgEzlX6F0QDMuA3AFA+iQoANQCG6AK4QAQiIQQAPABUoEAB7AIAOwAmCWK2IAaKAFVjQgHxQcAbx5QHUDQmAAuKIsP3HcYAAsIACcSdzNvB18AwPp3IR4AX15+cGhRCVIlKxw0yRk5eRZaYjJjTw8LXgFUsUl6TOthGulZBUKiBlxS4wBtMsUAXQrkwRyOeuymvNaado5Oj1LuwaSqqAARCAAzZE1kYGQ4TQa7RyhugGkoHagXQJ2Ac37YppJ5EU0QKypRuvfPyka6XYbw+FgSSR2GkCmxEAGNoABRVQiAC2YEwUBOjlwIlQsNw7ixpwczjc1AMmBK4WJkSCIRuwDumnu1NOtOi7luD2p8S8p1w2i2BMxrMcpPcbTYVOJPn8dM5jO5Moico5DKZLNOvOpuHufmQwqJxPF5KKHT5yvZ9K5zNFKqiMTONvuxmd-R5FocuAAVgBrdCGu1OCAuCUzNicT001XWxW25VQdmO51LHkJPirAAaDV9EBAcE2UCRqPREBWKSgAHlNOgQPAzaQYIE4GAEOMRadugApK5HXP5wsDdyKbv9FTqLS6THB0Om2ZkKDxKAAfg8o6g7k0EAAbkEEt1+wWPP1y4IAGJwOANau1+vzpsttvFtGYIY8TbiTSw-aHKAokBnp+34HJo8gPmA44aDoeg3nWFKNs2rbyM+pYWBYAAUYCIe44EAJTTvEfD-oBX4-po6E2DOZKSsU8xWhKmyXnRqqOrgqAiIE5DxPhAD0PFVucPDEUBZEUVRYbwYwxj0WcOLzGxuD9NJLESni2hcbx-EIoEzaBDwQA):

```
myFunction({ test: "possible1", other1: "foo", other2: "bar" }) // OK
myFunction({ test: "possible2", other1: ["a", "b"], other2: "bcd" }) // Error
```

Comment: Thank you, I just learnt about Mapped types that basically are loops. Because conditional types with extends are distributive, I thought I could use them as a loop... Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Drarig29 no problem :) Mapped types are really powerful! Nice thing to have in your TypeScript toolkit.